# PKCS11 certificate

Tags: c#, .net, security, certificate, digital-certificate

Does Dot NET supports PKCS11 certificates for HSM devices. If not, are there any other third party utilities available which supports pkcs11 certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "HSM device", so you will need to check the specifics of your requirements.

Otherwise .NET *does* support PKCS9, but no sign of PKCS11 in core .NET (for the former  [`System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs) namespace).

Outside of core .NET there are some search hits (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.clm.shared.profiletemplates.smartcardprovidertype(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: even I could find none till now and believe there exists none as of now

Comment: PKCS are just a bunch of standards ( just like RFCS ), PKCS#11 is a standard for using hardware crypto devices ( often called HSM - Hardware Security Module ).

PKCS#11 is an API standard, various HSM vendors ship PKCS#11 compliant drivers (dynamic/shared libraries) that a PKCS#11 aware program can load up and use to generate keys, import certs and do general crypto etc.

Comment: I can see a reference to P11 in your link but as I'm not ".net aware" I don't know where to use it : <blockquote>Two smart card provider types are supported by CLM: PKCS#11 and Base CSP.</blockquote> @DevilJin

Answer (score 3):

For PKCS11 you can use open source [Pkcs11Interop](https://www.pkcs11interop.net/). It works fine and contains alot of unit tests with examples of usage.

Answer (score 2):

This library does what you need:
http://www.ncryptoki.com

Answer (score 1):

You can easily call PKCS11 APIs from .net using statements like this:

```
    [DllImport("cryptoki.dll")]
    static extern ushort C_Initialize(int reserved);
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows, and .NET by the virtue of it being signed to be a Windows platform, has it's own alternatives to PKCS#11.

In .NET itself there is System.Security.Cryptography that has the concept of Key Storage Providers, in Windows there is CryptoAPI with its Cryptographic Service Providers and its smaller subset called minidrivers designed for Smart Cards.

In both cases applications built on the associated cryptographic APIs get to access cryptographic appliances like Hardware Security Modules that integrate with them.

All vendors will provide integration with one or more of these provider models so you can use these devices without the use of PKCS#11 if that is your interest.

If you need to use PKCS#11 for some reason, and there are cases where that might be needed, you should look at https://www.pkcs11interop.net/ as it provides a managed wrapper for the native PKCS#11 libraries provided by HSM vendors.

If you go down this route you can use SoftHSM (https://www.opendnssec.org/softhsm/) for testing if you don't have such a device handy, if you stay with the Windows cryptographic APIs you can do testing with the Virtual Smart Card solution that is included in Windows and this will do a reasonable job approximating the sort of issues you will have with a physical HSM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a .NET specialist but according to Google [PKIblackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-pki.php) has a toolkit for .NET that speaks PCKS#11. Then there exist some PKCS#11-CSP wrappers which allow to access PKCS#11 modules via CryptoAPI, for what I assume .NET world has many helpers. One of such wrappers is [CSP11](http://csp11.labs.libre-entreprise.org/)